# Do I really need to list.copy() a list before append?

Tags: python, list, sorting, append, extend

I have two lists,

```
list1 = [91, 95, 97, 99]
list2 = [92, 93, 96, 98]
```

Can I just use `list2.extend(list1)` if I want to merge them and arrange them with `list2.sort()`?

Or do I need to make a copy of it before extend?

```
list3 = list1.copy()
list3.extend(list2)
```

And why is my list not sorted if I do

```
list3 = []
list3.append(list1 + list2)
list3.sort()
print(list3)
```

Comment: What is the problem? .sort() sort the list in-place, if you want a new sorted list use sorted

Comment: It *is* sorted. Why do you think it isn't sorted? Note, `list3.append(list1 + list2)` creates a list with *one element* which will **always be sorted**

Comment: In any case, it really isn't clear what you are asking. You *can do whatever you want* provided you understand what you are doing (well, it would be ideal if you understood what you were doing before doing it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your last question:

```
list1 = [91, 95, 97, 99]
list2 = [92, 93, 96, 98]
list3 = []
list3.append(list1 + list2)
```

This appends a list inside a list. If you `print(list3)` you get
`[[91, 95, 97, 99, 92, 93, 96, 98]]`

The `.sort()` method attempts to sort the outer list, of which there is only 1 element, which can't be sorted any further. To sort that list you would need to do,
`list3[0].sort()`
Now printing list3 gives you,
'print(list3)`

> [[91, 92, 93, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do.  If you don't intend to use the original content of list2 (before merging and sorting) elsewhere in your program, then you don't need to make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to keep in mind which functions return a list and which ones modify/mutate the list the function is called on. Here is a summary:

- `extend`, `append` and `sort` mutates a list, but `sorted` returns a new list.

So yes you can extend one list with another and then sort it as you have done. You don't need to make a copy (unless you actually need to for some reason).

`+` does the same thing as `extend` when used with lists. Unfortunately, `list3.append(list1 + list2)` doesn't do what you think it does, `append` is for adding individual items to the end of a list, you need to use `+` or `extend` if you want to add one list to another as you had before, e.g. `new_list = list1 + list2 + list3`. Then you can sort and print it.